# Python - How to write data out to a new csv file

Tags: python, csv, append, output

Ok, so I'm fairly new to Python and I have a .csv file which contains data for racers names, start and finish times.  I need to calculate the time taken and output the additional information, plus the earlier data to a new .csv.

This is what I have so far:

```
import csv
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("runners_times.csv"))
for row in input_file:
    time_taken = float(row["finish_time"])-float(row["start_time"])
    print (row)
    print (time_taken)

with open("runners_times_appended.csv", "w+") as to_file:
        writer = csv.writer(to_file, delimiter=",")
        for row in input_file:
            writer.writerows(all)
```

This is creating the new .csv but the file is empty.  Your Help is gratefully appreciated.

Comment: did you try using 'wb' or 'w' instead of 'w+'?

Comment: i think you meant to have `writer.writerow(row)`?

Comment: Thanks.  Tried both - still got an empty .csv...

Comment: What is `all` in `writer.writerow(all)`? Also, please edit your question to reflect the suggestions from Kunkka and R Nar.

Comment: Thank you Austin A.  Forgive my lack of etiquette - this is the first time I have ever posted a thread anywhere, never mind among such esteemed minds.  This is also my first attempt at programming with Python, so I'm not quite sure what you mean by "edit your question to reflect the suggestions from Kunkka and R Nar"?  When I used the term (all) I did so on the understanding that this would write 'all' existing rows?

Comment: All fixed now - many thanks!

Comment: Do not change the question from it's original form unless you need to add information, correct mistakes or other changes that will make the question more clear or precise. Editing to add how you fixed the problem is not the appropriate way to use this site. Please read [ask] and [answer]. @AustinA your advice is not useful. Read the links too as it isn't how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't fully understand how are you using time_taken in your file which you are going to save.
As I understand you need to add/change column in your dataFrame/csvFile with time_taken. You could do it with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("runners_times.csv")
df["time_taken"] = df["finish_time"] - df["start_time"]
df.to_csv("new_name.csv")
```

Comment: Many thanks Anton, but my system doesn't like pandas: ImportError: No module named 'pandas'.  Will persevere :-).

Comment: you could find binary pandas package for windows [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Just find pandas, then download a wheel and install it with pip. It's very useful package for dataFrame/csvFiles processing. But you also will need install all packages from dependicies, i.e. `Requires numpy, dateutil, pytz, setuptools`

Comment: [link for downloading pandas wheel](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv
data_list = []
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("runners_times.csv"))
for row in input_file:
    time_taken = float(row["finish_time"])-float(row["start_time"])
    row.update({"time_taken":time_taken})
    data_list.append(row)
keys = data_list[0].keys()
with open("runners_times_appended.csv", "w") as fp:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(fp, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(data_list)
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul.  Tried this edit and got this error: >>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lcswife\OneDrive\St Leonards\2015-16\Yr 11\The Big Race\The Big Race5.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = [row+[time_taken]].  
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'list'
>>>  I may be doomed ;-)

Comment: Thanks Rahul - that has solved the problem of appending the time_taken, however. I still can't get the output to a csv file.  Grateful for your help.

Comment: Now a different error?  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:/Documents/2015-16/11L/05 - Reading and Writing Files/The Big Race/The Big Race6.py", line 13, in <module>
    dict_writer.writeheader()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\csv.py", line 141, in writeheader
    header = dict(zip(self.fieldnames, self.fieldnames))
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration.

Comment: Updated the answer. I missed the parenthesis while getting keys. Try again and tell me if it works.